# Symfony2 accessing values in base html

Tags: php, html, arrays, symfony, twig

I have a dynamic menu and in the top right corner I want to dinamically display the number of products I have in my cart. All my twigs extend base.html.twig in which I have this dynamic menu.

```
<div id="mainBody" class="container">
    <header id="header">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/mpshop/img/logo_title.png') }}" alt="Bootsshop"/></a>
    <div class="pull-right"> <br/>
        <a href="{{ path('product_summary') }}"> <span class="btn btn-mini btn-warning"> <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> [ {{ cart|length }} ] </span> </a>
        <a href="{{ path('product_summary') }}"><span class="btn btn-mini active">$155.00</span></a>
        <span class="btn btn-mini">&pound;</span>
        <span class="btn btn-mini">&euro;</span> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

However when I add `{{ cart|length }}` I am getting variable cart does not exist. Does base.html.twig has its own controller? How to give the base twig the cart with session so it could see my array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is create a helper class and include a method from that class in the menu (navbar?)

To do this you can make a regular Controller called for example HelperController.php then create a method within that new controller, like shownumberofproductsAction and then create a corresponding view file: shownumberofproducts.html.twig

Then in your top right menu simply call:

```
{% render controller("MySomethingBundle:Helper:shownumberofproducts") %}
```